# How do you auto layout constraint a notification label inside a button?

Tags: ios, autolayout, constraints

This is the screenshot of my issue.

[image]

My problem is the button label is not a view. I can not anchor that notification label to it. If I anchor that label to any of the sides, the screen size will affect it.

Example: 6s Plus

[image]

and iPhone SE

[image]

It's fine on the bigger phones.

Comment: Try subclassing a UIButton and add the badge count label to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way is to make a UIView with the badge and the title label in it and just overlay a UIButton with no title. This way you can constraint the badge label and the title label together.

Comment: This is based on discussion with Tech lead, I upped your answer @BhargavR because they are essentially the same except I don't have to subclass the UIButton.

Answer (score 1):

BhargavR has the right idea. Subclass UIButton and add the badge as a subview constrained to the button's textLabel (the UILabel it uses) property.